# Remove hex 1F from CSV file using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple CSV files from different sites within my company that contain multiple names and email addresses from several SQL databases that many different company users enter data into.  I have a SQL export program that exports the names and emails to CSV files.  I have noticed that occasionally some of the email addresses have the hex 0x1F separator either before or after the email address (in Notepad++ it looks like a black "US" box).

How can I write a simple batch file to find and remove just that separator from any CSV file that may have it. And save the output using/replacing the original file.  Preferably using simple batch commands, not Powershell or Java or anything else like that.  This will be running on a standard install of Windows 2008 R2 without any extra programs added.

**Example:**

**Directory:**
C:\Uploads

**Filenames (up to 23 files with a random 2 digit prefix followed by date):**
"a1-20151101.csv", "b2-20151101.csv", "cd-20151101.csv", etc.

**Inside CSV (FirstName;LastName;Email):**

John;Doe;john.doe@johndoe.com

Jane;Smith;jsmith@google.com

Comment: If possible don't reinvent the wheel and use [JREPL.BAT](http://dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which should run on W2k8: `call jrepl "\x1F" "" /m <"inputfile" >"outputfile"`

Comment: So would this work?: `@echo off
setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b C:\Uploads\*.csv') do (
    set "inputfile=%%i"
    call jrepl "\x1F" "" /m <"C:\Uploads\%inputfile%.csv" >"C:\Uploads\%inputfile%.csv"
)`  I tried it, but it appears to do nothing.

Comment: Nope. Don't use the intermediate variable. Specify `"%%i"` directly and don't use the same output name. For example `call .... <"%%i" >"%%i.tmp" & move/y "%%i.tmp" "%%i"`

Comment: Ok, I figured out my initial error causing the file not to work (had an extra opening parenthesis).  Now I am getting the error `' jrepl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.  Is this a standard file included with Windows, or do I need to download it?  I could not find a download link from your previous link.

Comment: Ok, I realized the that code was included on that website, so I created the batch.  It worked perfectly.  Thank you wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

You *could* spend precious time writing some 400-line behemoth of a `cmd` file.

Or you could simply go and get the `tr` program from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) (ports of the popular UNIX tools to native Windows) which is perfectly suited to doing this sort of thing.

Then your batch file will basically consist of the line:

```
tr -d "\37" inputFile >outputFile
```

The `tr` program is contained within the [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package.